# Wave like seek bar for music player app in android jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-progressbar

[image: Music progress bar]

Can I implement this type of music player seek bar to my music player app in Jetpack Compose (Not in the notification, inside my actual app)?
If so, what is its name, and which library should I use?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77927207/8583692)

Answer (score 1):

I have found this library, [wavy-slider](https://github.com/mahozad/wavy-slider) which could give you similar seek bar effect by tuning it a little.